# Sympy solve complex algebraic equation

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve a transcendental algebraic equation

`1 / sqrt(x) = -2 * log10( 0.0015 / (3.7 * 0.25) + 2.51 / (267471 * sqrt(x)))`

In reality 0.0015, 0.25 and 267471 are input parameters with names ks, D an Re.

I have tried to write the code in sympy:

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, log, sqrt
x = symbols('x')
eq1 = Eq( 1 / sqrt(x), x)
eq2 = Eq( -2 * log((0.0015 / (3.7*0.25)) + (2.51 / (267471.0183 * (sqrt(x))))), x)
        
sol = solve((eq1, eq2), (x))
sol
```

I, however, do not get a solution nor an error with this code. I know there is a solution as I have calculated it by hand as well. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The two equations are inconsistent.

Comment: @oscarbenjamin Could you explain on that a little further?

Comment: Solve the first equation for `x` (`x=1`) and plug it into the second equation. The second is False. They don't agree on the value of `x` which will set them *both* equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The single equation that you are trying to handle in two parts has no solution (though it may for different constants). It looks like you rewrote the equation `a = b` as two equation `x = a and x = b` but that will not be true in general (though it will be True if you replace `x` with `y`).

There is no need to do this, however, since you can just solve the single, initial equation. So define

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> f = lambda ks, D, Re: x-1/(2*log(ks/3.7/D+2.51/Re/sqrt(x), 10))**2
```

and use `nsolve` to get a solution for different values of `ks`, `D` and `Re`, e.g.

```py
>>> nsolve(f(.0015,.25,267471), 1)
0.0324341514218781
```

The ability of `nsolve` to find a solution of a nonlinear expression will depend on the shape of the function near the root and the quality of your initial guess. The function has been rewritten in the form that was suggested to be well behaved (by @lastchance).

Comment: Apologies, yes, the e is indeed not for Euler's constant as @lastchance said.

Comment: The answer has been updated. The OP has been edited, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit solution to the Colebrook-White equation (for friction factor, lambda or f, in a pipe). Instead you can solve it numerically by single-point iteration. This works well because the logarithm changes relatively slowly.

Rearrange your equation as

x = 1 / ( 2 * log10(...) )<sup>2</sup>

and iterate from a typical value (between 0.001 and 0.01 - see a Moody diagram).

It has a perfectly good solution for your given parameters; (the logarithm here turns out to be negative). The solution has historically been plotted on a Moody chart: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moody_chart

```
import math

def Colebrook_White( ks, D, Re ):
   # Solve Colebrook-White equation for friction factor lambda, given
   # ks = equivalent sand roughness, D = pipe diameter, Re = Reynolds number

   x = 0.01        # initial guess
   xold = x + 1
   while abs( x - xold ) > 1.0e-6:
      xold = x
      x = 1.0 / ( 2.0 * math.log10( ks / 3.7 / D + 2.51 / Re / math.sqrt( x ) ) ) ** 2
   return x


ks = 0.0015    # equivalent sand roughness (in m)
D = 0.25       # pipe diameter (in m)
Re = 267471    # Reynolds number

print( "Friction factor, lambda = ", Colebrook_White( ks, D, Re ) )
```

Output:

```
Friction factor, lambda =  0.03243415139301062
```

Comment: Thank you lastchance, there is indeed no explicit solution for the Colebrook-White. Your approach however is indeed perfect for what I was looking for. Thank you so much!